# Proof of integral inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

How does one prove (without making use of any approximations whatsoever) the following inequality:

$$\int_1^2 \left(\ln(x)\right)^{2013}dx\leq\dfrac{1}{2^{2013}}.$$

Comment: What makes you think that inequality is correct? Where did you get it from?

Comment: The given inequality is equivalent to 
$$\int_1^2 (2 \ln x)^{2013} dx \le 1$$

Now note that as the integrand is positive and increasing on the interval,
$$\int_1^2 (2 \ln x)^{2013} dx > \int_{1.9}^2 (2 \ln x)^{2013} > 0.1 \times (2 \ln 1.9)^{2013} > 2\cdot 10^{217}$$
so the LHS is in fact significantly greater than $1$, and the inequality is **false**.